# Redux fails assigning integer value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In CategoryFeed class, I have something like following:

```
class CategoryFeed extends Component {
...
componentDidMount() {
const {
      params,
      currentForum,
      updateCurrentForum,
    } = this.props;

    alert(params.fid);
    updateCurrentForum(params.fid);
    alert(currentForum);
}
...
export default connect(
  (state) => { return {
    currentForum: state.app.currentForum,
...
(dispatch) => { return {
    updateCurrentForum: (currentForum) => { dispatch(updateCurrentForum(currentForum)); },
...
```

This is what updateCurrentForum looks like:

```
export const updateCurrentForum = (currentForum) => {
  alert("inside is " + currentForum);
  return {
    type: UPDATECURRENTFORUM,
    payload: currentForum,
  };
};
```

In Reducer, I have defined like:

```
case UPDATECURRENTFORUM:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        currentForum: action.payload,
      });
```

Here is how it supposed to work from my expectation.

1. When the CategoryFeed is loaded, it alerts params.fid (let's say params.fid = 1). params.fid is actually additional string after my main url (e.g. if url was http://localhost/1, then params.fid is 1).
2. Then it stores the value of params.fid (=1) to currentForum via Redux
3. After I set currentForum by putting payload value to it, then I tried alert the value of currentForum in componentDidMount(). However, it does not show "1" but it shows "undefined". It looks like redux has failed putting params.fid to currentForum.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `console.log('__props__', this.props.currentForum)` in your component's `render` method, you might be doing everything in a correct way, but the asynchronicity of Redux dispatching actions can not provide the value immediatly, such like, it won't be able to put the data into the store when it comes for your second `alert` to execute..

Comment: FYI, the hint is in `const` keyword - since `currentForum` is a constant, it will NOT change. any changes will be visible only during a next render (when a method is executed again with different props, but for `componentDidMount` that will never happen as mentioned in the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to get the updated value of `currentForum` in `componentDidMount()`. This is because `componentDidMount()` only runs once the component is mounted.

Changes to props in `componentDidMount()` will cause the component to re-render. So the updated value will be accessible in the `render()` or `componentDidUpdate()` cycles.

You can move your `alert` or `console.log` to the render method and you should see the updated value

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` will be called after component is inserted into DOM tree and inside that you called `updateCurrentForum(params.fid)` which will update `currentForum` but this change will be caught in `componentDidUpdate`. for more details you can see lifecycle diagram of component http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

currently `currentForum` holds value from

```
const {
  params,
  currentForum,
  updateCurrentForum,
} = this.props;
```

which might be undefined currently. try to assign some value in props and see if it changes from `undefined` to `value` you provided